# Dynamically shortened text with “Read More” link using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a text and I want to dynamically shortened the text with “Read More” link using JavaScript. I use the following JavaScript code:

```
var limitDesc = -1;
function ResponsiveDesc() {
//var limitDesc = 100;
//var isHTML = RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/(<([^>]+)>)/i);
var chars = $("#ResponsiveDescription").html();
if (chars.length > limitDesc) {
    var visiblePart = $("<span> " + chars.substr(0, limitDesc - 1) + "   </span>");
    var dots = $("<span class='dots'>... </span>");
    var hiddenPart = $("<span class='more'>" + chars.substr(limitDesc - 1) + "</span>");
    var readMore = $("<span class='read-more'>More</span>");

    readMore.click(function () {
        $(this).prev().remove(); // remove dots
        $(this).next().show(); //show hiddenPart
        $(this).remove(); // remove readMore
    });

    $("#ResponsiveDescription").empty()
        .append(visiblePart)
        .append(dots)
        .append(readMore)
        .append(hiddenPart);
}
}
$(document).ready(function () {
if (limitDesc > 0 && $(window).width() < 500) {
    ResponsiveDesc();
}
});
```

The main problem is that I don't what this code to cut my text in the middle of a word or a link. What is the best way to solve this problem ?
I can manually change the "limitDesc" variable on each page but when the content of the page is dynamic, it's impossible.
Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery.dotdotdot (http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string at the last whitespace before your length limit.
You can determine it using `lastIndexOf()`:

```
limitDesc = chars.lastIndexOf(" ", limitDesc);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp